# Javascript API call from button not returning value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, api

I have an HTML button which OnClick calls a Javascript function to reset a password on a 3rd party website.  I want it to return a message to the user depending on the result of the call but no matter what i try to do the value is always blank when the call is finished.

The section that checks the pwd length is fine and returns to the page with the values in the hidden fields but if the pwd is fine and the API call is made I only get blanks in the hidden fields.

On looking at the Console log i have seen that i get the following messages:
[image: console log messages]

but i still end up with nothing in my hidden field and my last console.log message doesn't seem to do anything either.

Here's my function, if anyone can offer any help it would be much appreciated.

```
function resetPassword() {

                console.log("in the function");

                var pwd = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
                var memberID = document.getElementById("hiddenUsername").value;


                if (pwd.length < 6 || pwd.length > 10) {
                    document.getElementById("resultHide").value = "pwd";
                }
                else {
                    console.log("pwd is ok");

                    var settings = {
                        "url": "https://test.com",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "timeout": 0,
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "data": JSON.stringify({ "auth": "123456", "member_id": memberID, "password": pwd }),
                    };

                    document.getElementById("resultHide").value = "";

                    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                        if (response.success == true) {
                            console.log("Success");
                            document.getElementById("resultHide").value = "true";
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(response.error);
                            document.getElementById("resultHide").value = "false";
                            document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").value = response.error;
                        }
                    }).fail(function () {
                        //we might want to do something here like display message to say they are not eligible to participate etc
                        console.log("Failure");

                        document.getElementById("resultHide").value = "fail";
                        document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").value = "API call failure";
                    })

                }

                console.log(document.getElementById("resultHide").value);

            }
```

Thanks

Comment: `resultHide` is input field or div ?

Comment: Its a hidden input field